# Restore state after returning from the Image Picker

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a text field in my app, and a button to open the image picker. If I enter some text in the text field, and then go take a picture, then the text in the text field disappears after I return from the camera. What's the proper way of saving/restoring the UI state in such cases in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing code, but when the UIImagePickerController is dismissed the parent controller will call ViewWill/DidAppear.  If you change the text of the UITextView in ViewWill/DidAppear then you will lose any input text.

Comment: You know what, that was it. Thanks! What a stupid mistake. Is viewDidLoad a more appropriate place for initing the UI?

Comment: My general rule of thumb is to init the input values in ViewDidLoad and use ViewWillAppear for layout issues (with storyboards layouts will often be setup after ViewDidLoad is called).  If you are reusing the controller often, you might be better off just creating a valueInit or somesuch to reset the input values.